# save session in http request swift

Tags: ios, json, http, session, swift

in my app I'm using JSON and I made a session recently so if I would like to make some http request to get data for a specific user, the user must log in before (also used by http request).
in the safari when I entering the url's of login and then the url of receive data, it does that as needed.
but in my app, I first call login and then the url for getting data, but it's probably starting a new session in every url request which leads me to get an error and not receive the data.
my url request function is:

```
static func urlRequest (adress: String, sessionEnded: (NSDictionary->Void)?){
    println(adress)
    var urli = NSURL(string: adress)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: urli!)
    var rVal = "";
     self.task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urli!) {(data, response, error) in
        var parseError: NSError?
        let parsedObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
            options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,
            error:&parseError)
        let po = parsedObject as NSDictionary
        if let a = sessionEnded{
            sessionEnded!(po)
        }
    }
    task!.resume()

}
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have shared only half of the puzzle with us, the client code. We can't comment on why the app isn't working with a clearer picture of what the server API. For example, once you "log in", how do subsequent queries confirm that the request is coming from valid session. Furthermore, you report that "every url request which leads me to get an error". Well, what error do you receive? You have to be far more specific regarding the precise errors/crashes you are receiving. BTW, are you logging on to some service with a well-defined API or are you writing that code yourself, too?

---

Having said that, I might suggest a few refinements to this method:

1. The `sessionEnded` (which I've renamed `completionHandler` to conform to informal standard naming conventions), probably should return an optional `NSError` object, too, so the caller can detect if there was an error.
2. Your unwrapping of the `sessionEnded` completion handler can be simplified to use `?`.
3. When you parse the object, you should feel free to perform the optional cast, too.
4. You probably want to detect a network error (in which case `data` would be `nil`) and return the network `NSError` object.
5. Minor point, but I'd probably also rename the function to conform to Cocoa naming conventions, using a verb to start the name. Perhaps something like `performURLRequest`.
6. This is your call, but I'd be inclined to have the method return the `NSURLSessionTask`, so that the caller could use that task object if it wanted to (e.g. save the task object so that it could `cancel` it later if it wanted to).

Thus, that yields something like:

```
func performURLRequest (address: String, completionHandler: ((NSDictionary!, NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionTask {
    let url = NSURL(string: address)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        if data == nil {
            sessionEnded?(nil, error)
        } else {
            var parseError: NSError?
            let parsedObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error:&parseError) as? NSDictionary
            completionHandler?(parsedObject, parseError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return task
}
```

And you'd invoke it like:

```
performURLRequest("http://www.example.com/some/path") { responseDictionary, error in
    if responseDictionary == nil {
        // handle error, e.g.
        println(error)
        return
    }

    // use `responseDictionary` here
}
```